# Updating a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to update a csv file, `https://www.kaggle.com/carolzhangdc/imdb-5000-movie-dataset`.

At the end of this csv file I am trying to append a new url to the image of the movie.

my code is below

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

with open('movie_metadata.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print('Column names are {}'.format(", ".join(row)))
            row[-1] = "movie_links"
            line_count += 1
        else:
            imdb_link = row[17]
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(imdb_link).read(), features="html.parser")
            link = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'poster'})
            if link:
                row[-1] = link[0].find('img')['src']
            line_count += 1
    print('Processed {} lines.'.format(line_count))
```

I am creating a new row at `row[-1]` and trying to update the csv file `if link:`

But it's not updating my csv file at all, it stays the same after I run my code.

Comment: Seems like you didn't write back?

Comment: You are using the csv reader. The reader does not write. Use the csv writer to write.

Comment: Trying to modify the CSV in place will be much harder than you need. You need to read the whole file in, create the new contents, and overwrite the whole file in 1 go

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize you overwrite the last element in the array `row`? You should `append()` instead of changing `[-1]`. Try:

`row.append("movie_links")` instead of `row[-1] = "movie_links"`

and

`row.append(link[0].find('img')['src'])` instead of `row[-1] = link[0].find('img')['src']`.

Then, to actually write the CSV file, use `csv.writer` with the new row (documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Note, `row + ["movie links"]` for the first one is another way to append. Using `[-1]` Overwrites the last element instead of appending! Let me know if you want me to code you the csv writing portion.